# Allow empty cms page content

Tags: magento

When using a cms page in magento I sometimes need an empty content section. Most times this is for my homepage. But magento forces me to put something in content before it can be saved.

Is there a way to get magento to allow empty cms page content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Edit_Tab_Content::_prepareForm()` method dispatches the [`adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Content.php#L98) event. You can observe this event, grab the  field from the form object which is passed into the event, and change its `required` property to `false`.

Comment: I think this is probably the best answer but it shame that there is so much work for such simple task.

Comment: Well, an EAV entity could have this done via upgrade script. An observer is just 2 config files and a model class. I can think of several frameworks for which this change would be a maintenance headache.

Answer (score 8):

You can use an empty div or span

Answer (score 5):

This is a quick and dirty fix, you should really override the admin class so you won't lose the change when you next upgrade.

Anyways, in file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Content.php`, in `function _prepareForm()`, line 82, change:

```
$contentField = $fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
    'name'      => 'content',
    'style'     => 'height:36em;',
    'required'  => true,
    'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled,
    'config'    => $wysiwygConfig
));
```

to

```
    $contentField = $fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
        'name'      => 'content',
        'style'     => 'height:36em;',
        'required'  => false,
        'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled,
        'config'    => $wysiwygConfig
    ));
```

Comment: Save the changes in app/code/local instead of app/code/core, and this fix becomes much less dirty. Works on 1.9.1.0

Answer (score 4):

add `<div>&zwj;</div>` inside your empty elements to stop magento cms from removing them

Answer (score 2):

Its not particularly elegant, but you can just enter `&nbsp;` and/or hide the content via CSS

Comment: Is sort of what I been doing till now. Was hoping that there existed a config option